# Is it possible to format Display attribute's Name property value of MVC Model class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, displayattribute

What I mean is, e.g.

```
[DataType(DataType.Text)]
[Display(Name = "Corporation / Entreprise")]
public string Corporation { get; set; }
```

Would it be possible to apply a line break after the '/' in the Name of the Display attribute?
So when the View page displaying the label value which set in the Model:

```
<td class="col-md-6" style="font-weight:bold">
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Corporation)
</td>
```

It would show something like:

```
Corporation / 
Entreprise
```

Instead of

```
Corporation / Entreprise
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you put a `\n` in the attribute property value? If it doesn't render a newline, I'd consider rolling my own with some reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `<br/>` attribute in displayattribute and display it as `Html.Raw` in the view. like this:

Model:

```
[DataType(DataType.Text)]
[Display(Name = "Corporation / <br/> Entreprise")]
public string Corporation { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<td class="col-md-6" style="font-weight:bold">
      @Html.Raw(@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Corporation))
</td>
```

Test Result:

[image]

Comment: Just a quick question, would I be able to use @Html.Raw to the label tag which uses the model value set for Corporation like <label asp-for="Corporation">? Thanks.