# Is it possible to not encode the Label tag value rendered in ASP.NET Core HtmlHelper?

Tags: encoding, asp.net-core-mvc, html-helper

I asked a similar question a while back:
[Is it possible to format Display attribute's Name property value of MVC Model class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73144236/is-it-possible-to-format-display-attributes-name-property-value-of-mvc-model-cl/73146330#73146330)

I am wondering would it be possible to not apply encoding in the ASP.NET Core `HtmlHelper.Label` tag?

What I have now is:

```
<label asp-for="CorporationName" class="control-label"></label>
```

I understand it will render the html .

Like so:

```
<label class="control-label" for="CorporationName">Corporation / <br/>Entreprise</label>
```

with the text value defined in this model class:

```
[DataType(DataType.Text)]
[Display(Name = "Corporation / <br/> Enterprise")]
public string Corporation { get; set; }
```

So I am wondering if it is possible to apply something similar to `@Html.Raw` to the asp-for attribute value in the label tag above so it will show as:

```
Corporation /
Enterprise
```

Or I need to write my own label class so it will do the encoding?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your requirement can be known as, you want to use tag helper and display `[Display(Name = "Corporation / Enterprise")]` to display as `Corporation / </br> Enterprise`.

Basically, you are trying to change the html content appearance, and you want to realize it via taghelper, but actually there's no such feature, you may try to create a custom taghelper like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43463145/custom-tag-helper-replace-the-html-tag). But I think it's too complex.

In my humble opinion, you can modify the html content by js. But the easiest way to add linebreaker into html content is `</br>`, so my test code looks like below, it worked for me:

```
<div>
    <label id="CorporationLabor" asp-for="Corporation" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Corporation" class="form-control" />
</div>
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#CorporationLabor").html("Corporation / </br> Enterprise!!!");
        });
    </script>
}
```